# Lie on the same plane vs. Lie in the same plane

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

We in mathematics say (so if you'll have to use, what will sound natural to you "on/in"?):

> Two objects are coplanar if they both lie **in** the same plane.

Or

> Two objects are coplanar if they both lie **on** the same plane.

So what sounds natural: "on" or "in" or both of them sound equally natural?

Also, is there any AmE-BrE difference?

Comment: I would recommend you the book 'English Prepositions Explained' by Seth Lindstromberg. With this book, you can develop a more intuitive and more correct use of prepositions in English.

Comment: @johann_ka  While that's possibly a good resource, why don't you just quote what it would say about this situation?  I'd be curious to know, considering **both** are valid prepositions, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are completely natural, but imply different ways of looking at the spatial orientation of the elements.

"*In* the same plane" is probably the more accurate from the mathematical perspective, since a plane has no depth.  A point cannot rest "on" the plane the way a cup would rest on a table, since that would mean it is *above* the plane and therefore not part of the plane.

However, "*on* the same plane" is a common expression.  Even though they should know it represents a mathematical fallacy, mathematicians persist in using the same language to describe these spatial relationships that they would use for real-world objects.

So, use whichever sounds better to you.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of a *flat* object (in geometry), we assume that all its points belong to some plane or lie **in** that plane:

> Given a line **in** a plane, there exists at least one point in the plane
>   that is not on the line. If two **points lie in a plane**, the line
>   containing them lies **in** the plane.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point%E2%80%93line%E2%80%93plane_postulate

If that plane is the same for two such objects, those two are coplanar, so sentence 1 is correct. It's different in case of putting something **on** a flat list of some material (consider e. g. something shown ***in*** a picture vs a fly **on** that picture).